# Show that $S_n= \sqrt{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \theta) / \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2$ converges in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, asymptotics, probability-limit-theorems

Studying for quals, looking for some help on this.

Let $X_i$, where $i = 1,2, \ldots, n$, be iid with common pdf $f(x) = \frac{1}{\theta} e^{-x/\theta}$ for $x>0$ and $0$ otherwise.

Let $S_n = \sqrt{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \theta) / \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2$.  Show that $S_n$ converges in distribution and derive its limiting distribution.

What I know:

- $E(X_i) = \theta$.
- $Var(X_i) = \theta^2$
- Convergence in Probability is stronger than Convergence in Distribution
- Convergence in Probability definition is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P([X_n - X | \ge \epsilon ] = 0$ (also know equiv. definitions).
- If $X_n \rightarrow X$ and $Y_n \rightarrow Y$ in probability then $X_nY_n \rightarrow XY$ in probability.

I left out the convergence in distribution definitions because I think that what I need to do is show that $\sqrt{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \theta)$ converges in probability and $\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2$ converges in probability, then $S_n = \sqrt{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \theta) / \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2$ converges in probability and this converges in distribution.

I have no idea how to go about finding the limiting distribution.

Any help would be most appreciated...

-IdleMathGuy

Comment: find the moment generating function of $S_n$ and take its limit as $n \to \infty$

Comment: It is not clear which part of the answer below does not address your query.

Comment: Four things:  1) I see you multiplied the numerator and the denominator by 1/n.  I take it that is because we are dealing with a sequence of random samples, $X_1, X_2, ...$.  2) Exactly how does the numerator converge using the CLT?  I take it $\theta$ is $\mu$ here?  3) Exactly how does the denominator converge to a constant using the weak law of large numbers?  4) What exactly is the limiting distribution when the numerator and denominator converge?

Comment: Some background.  This is considered a more difficult problem on the comp exam.  I can handle basic pdf/cdf, transformations, expectations, co-variance, order statistics, etc.  However, the asymptotic parts are difficult for me.  I'm looking for a good example to study the concepts from.

Comment: How am I supposed to receive these comments if you do not ping me (using @) or do not comment under the answer?

Comment: @StubbornAtom my apologies.  It's simply lack of sleep this semester with coursework, teaching, and studying for comp.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Since $$S_n = \frac{\sqrt n\left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i-\theta\right)}{\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i^2}\,,$$

this is a simple application of [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) where the numerator converges in law to a normal distribution using central limit theorem and the denominator converges in probability to a constant using the (weak) law of large numbers.